# Facebook feed on website using javascript. Is it secure?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I have a client who would like the most recent post displayed on their site (along with like and comment counts) plus a link to the actual post. Their page is public, so I can view it in a browser without being logged in. Let's just say it's Nike.

http://www.facebook.com/nike (public)

http://graph.facebook.com/nike/feed (wait, i need to authenticate to see this?)

I went through the trouble of setting up a dummy app on a dummy account, got an access_token an was able to pull what I needed using javascript(Jquery). The reason I'm doing it this way is because the client has sensitive data and other apps/sites on this server and does not want to involve their IT department to QA my code.

Before final handoff, they'll likely set up their own facebook app on their account. This would significantly raise the stakes if someone decided they wanted to play with that access_token.

I'm mostly a front-end guy who's done some small php sites/apps, so what would you recommend I do?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I've outlined the one thing I've been limited to. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about facebook in particular, but typically if you want to protect api access credentials you would proxy the request through your server, and just send the results to the client (so the access key only exists on the server). Alternately, and I'm not sure that facebook provides this, some APIs will give you a user token, which does not expose your access key, but allows the client to call the api.

Comment: I definitely hear you and if this were for a client without those internal security considerations, it would be done quicker than me typing up this question. I may go down that road (client side), but that comes with other considerations because this is a very high volume site that is US only now but will be international in time.

Comment: I'd just pose the question to the client, we can store the access keys securely on the server, or we can put them on the client and hope for the best. Let them pick whichever they think is right.